# How to drop a column from a list?

Tags: r

Good afternoon :

Suppose i have the following list of dataframes :

```
[[4]]
[[4]]$L.1
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width v
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 1
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2 1
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 1
11           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2 1
16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4 1
19           5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3 1
20           5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3 1
21           5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2 1



[[4]]$L.2
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width v
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2 2
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 2
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 2
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 2
8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2 2
9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 2
10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 2
12           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2 2
13           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1 2



[[4]]$L.3
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width v
15           5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2 3
17           5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4 3
136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 3.
```

My question is how to drop the column `v`?

I tried without success:

```
lapply(L, "[", -v)
```

Thank you in advance for help !

Comment: It seems that your list is within another list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
#Code
L <- lapply(L, function(x){x$v<-NULL;x})
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
#Code 2
L <- lapply(L, function(x){x %>% dplyr::select(-v)})
```

Comment: @TouMou It is always a pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

`L <- L[,-5]` where 5 is the column number

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `setdiff`

```
L1 <- lapply(L, function(x) x[setdiff(names(x), 'v')])
```